# How to bind Items to Listview in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Sorry for my bad English.
Here is my Problem:

My Listview, I think you see my Problem:

[image: My Listview, i think you see my Problem]

Here is my code:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Name}" SelectionChanged="lvUsers_SelectionChanged" Margin="10" Name="lvUsers">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Mail" Width="150"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Here is the c# Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<User> items = new List<User>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42, Mail = "john@doe-family.com" });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39, Mail = "jane@doe-family.com" });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 7, Mail = "sammy.doe@gmail.com" });
        DataContext = items;
    }
}

public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Mail { get; set; }
}
```

I want to bind the List-Items to my listview.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: As you seems to be using [this](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/) tutorial. The solution is to remove `ItemsSource="{Binding Name}"` because you are using `DataContext = items;`. and to bind your GridViewColumn  to the correct item property `{Binding Name}`, `{Binding Age}`, `{Binding Mail}`

Comment: Thanks on every one!!! IT WORKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used WPF much myself, but a wild guess on what could fix your issue:

Replace this line:

```
DataContext = items;
```

with this line:

```
DataContext = this;
```

You want to bind the DataContext to a class, not to a specific collection (I would probably create a seperate class called something along the lines of MainWindowViewModel, but one thing at a time).

Then in the first tag of your ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Name}" SelectionChanged="lvUsers_SelectionChanged" Margin="10" Name="lvUsers">
```

Replace it with this line:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding items}" SelectionChanged="lvUsers_SelectionChanged" Margin="10" Name="lvUsers">
```

You want your ItemsSource to be the name of the collection, not what you actually want to use from that collection.

That means that you can later, inside the ListView, use the set binding to access the collection properties:

```
{Binding Name} , {Binding Age} , {Binding Mail}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, changes in the xaml code to make your code work:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding }" SelectionChanged="lvUsers_SelectionChanged" Margin="10" Name="lvUsers">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="120"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Age"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" Width="50"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Mail"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Mail}" Width="150"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

These are all the changes that are needed. You can do improvements to your code by using MVVM principles, to separate your code, Notifiable classes to allow the UI to update when you add/remove elements from your collections.

Hope this helps,
Silviu.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use below line

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding items}" SelectionChanged="lvUsers_SelectionChanged" Margin="10" Name="lvUsers">
```